# Python Exporting a file via pyexcel (csv to xlsx)

Tags: python, csv, export, xlsx, pyexcel

I have made a little code using pyexcel to convert all files in my folder from csv to xlsx. But I want to export it with the same name (instead of file1.xlsx) as it was for each file in the folder. Can you help please?

```
from pyexcel.cookbook import merge_all_to_a_book
import pyexcel.ext.xlsx
import glob
import os
os.chdir(“/Users/vanicek/Desktop/csv2xlsx” )

i = 0

for file in glob.glob(“*.csv”):
       while os.path.exists(“file%s.xlsx” % i):
               i+=1
       merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob(“*.csv”), “file%s.xlsx” % i)

print “Exported.”
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import glob
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook


for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):

workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for r, row in enumerate(reader):
        for c, col in enumerate(row):
            worksheet.write(r, c, col)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Thank, but it crashes with error in encoding:


`Traceback (most recent call last):
 File “csv2xlsx_export.py”, line 11, in <module>
   with open(csvfile, ‘rt’, encoding=‘utf8’) as f:
TypeError: ‘encoding’ is an invalid keyword argument for this function
Exception Exception: Exception(‘Exception caught in workbook destructor. Explicit close() may be required for workbook.’,) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object at 0x10d9eac90>> ignored`